# How to remove illegal characters from string in eWam?

Tags: ewam

Once user enters a data for eg abc$sdfgh% I want to remove the illegal characters from this text.Could someone please suggest me how this can be achieved in eWam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the wyde framework you should option 1.
if not please read options 2. and 3.

1. Use WFTypes methods like RemoveSpaceAndSpecialCharFrom

WFTypes.RemoveSpaceAndSpecialCharFrom(thisCString)

```
 function RemoveSpaceAndSpecialCharFrom(thisCString : CString) return CString
    _Result = WFTypes.RemoveSpaceAndSpecialCharFrom(thisCString)
 endFunc
```

2. Search for a similar method in the P&C framework
3. Build your own method something like this:

   ```
    function RemoveSpecialCharFrom(thisCString : CString) return CString
       var pCurChar : .Char

       _Result = thisCString
       forEach pCurChar in _Result
          switch pCurChar.
             when 'â', 'à'
                pCurChar. = 'a'
             endWhen
             when 'é', 'ê', 'è'
                pCurChar. = 'e'
             endWhen
             when 'î', 'ì'
                pCurChar. = 'i'
             endWhen
             when 'ô', 'ò'
                pCurChar. = 'o'
             endWhen
             when 'ù', 'û'
                pCurChar. = 'u'
             endWhen
             when 'ç'
                pCurChar. = 'c'
             endWhen
             when 'À', 'Â'
                pCurChar. = 'A'
             endWhen
             when 'È', 'É', 'Ê'
                pCurChar. = 'E'
             endWhen
             when 'Î', 'Ï', 'Ì'
                pCurChar. = 'I'
             endWhen
             when 'Ç'
                pCurChar. = 'C'
             endWhen
             when 'Ô', 'Ò'
                pCurChar. = 'O'
             endWhen
             when 'Ù', 'Û'
                pCurChar. = 'U'
             endWhen
             when '/', '\', '(', ')', '.', ',', ';', ':', '?', '-', '&', '$', '[', ']', 
                '''', '"', '=', '+', '~', '`', '^', '@', '{', '}', '!', '<', '>', '²', 
                '£', '¤', '%', '°'
                pCurChar. = '_'
             endWhen
          endSwitch
       endFor
    endFunc
   ```